# Ubuntu 10.04 bad install...now Mac won't boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, install, grub, macintosh

I've been having a problem all day.  It all started when I tried to partition my HD to install Ubuntu with bootcamp on my mac.  The install froze and when I restarted the Apple logo was replaced with a "do not enter" sign (circle with slash).  I've been searching forums for a solution and even tried to run a LiveCD but that failed.  I think I need to remove GRUB from my MBR.  Anyone have some suggestions/help? Much appreciated.

Comment: you could also boot ubuntu again and restore GRUB

Comment: Restore the apple bootloader/MBR record from the OSX disk. It sounds like something got into conflict between GRUB and Apple's boot loader. Once you rewrite the MBR with Apple's bootloader, grub should disappear.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try booting from an OSX boot disc?
Then as it wants to start (re)installing OSX, just stop and go into disk utilities
to see if you can restore your OSX partition as the boot partition.
I suppose the Live CD you are referring to is an Ubuntu 10.04 cd, right?

Tell me what you've tried already

Did you figure it out on your own ? 
If so,could you perhaps tell us how you did proceed ?

Comment: Really Kevin ? taking time to put caps on my answer ? :)